# Array to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a simple array to a multidimensional array.

The Array I currently have

```
Array = (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I would like to convert this Array to be like this

```
Array = ([1, 2], [3, 4]);
```

Any help is welcome, thanks already.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this: A.reduce((rows, key, index) => (index % 2 == 0 ? rows.push([key]) 
: rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows, []); But this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Don't "hide" relevant information in a comment. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67262782/edit) your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function TwoDimensional(arr, size) 
{
  var res = []; 
  for(var i=0;i < arr.length;i = i+size)
  res.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
  console.log(res);
}
```

Pretty easy when it works! Thanks